Horror movie where a demon comes out of a scary book and frighten a young boy and his mother
I know it is not very old. 
It is this young boy with temper issues who gets suspended from school, then his mom finds this scary book and reads it to him. After that, the book releases a demon which terrorizes the kid and makes the mom go mentally insane. 
When she first realizes that a demon is haunting them, she burns the book with lighter fluid, but it gets worse after that. The demon makes her have vivid hallucination, she has memory lapses and states where you can't tell whether she is conscious or not. She gets super mad and almost kills her kid, and actually kills their dog by snapping its neck. 
Some other significant events in the movie are; the boy pushes his cousin out of a tree-house when she is bullying him, the mom goes to the police station and sees the demon,the mom hallucinates cockroaches climbing out of the wall, and the kid ties the mom up in the basement and she throws up blood. 
They eventually defeat the demon, at-least I think, I don't know how to interpret the ending. What is this movie called?

Welcome to M&TV StackExchange. You provided plot details which is good. +1 for this. Do you also remember possible release year, language, and possible country of origin? If you do, please add them so that it can also help identify this movie.

The @IvanaMNE answer is correct, should be accepted

The movie is "The Babadook" from 2014.
Wikipedia contains a description of the movie, which matching with the details that you provided.
You can see trailer here.
